# Maybe a folklore natural map between reflexive pullbacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the introduction of [HK04], it is proposed that for a morphism between varieties $f:X'\to X$, and a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, there is a natural map $\alpha:f^*(\mathcal{F}^{\vee\vee})\to (f^*\mathcal{F})^{\vee\vee}$, where $\mathcal{F}^{\vee\vee}$ is the double dual of $\mathcal{F}$. It maybe a folklore natural map which is well-known for experts. How to construct it? I tried to find the construction of $\alpha$, but there is no article constructing $\alpha$, and I tried to construct $\alpha$ myself, and the natural map gives us
$$ f^*(\mathcal{F}^{\vee\vee})=f^*\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F}^{\vee},\mathcal{O}_{X'})\to \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X'}}(f^*(\mathcal{F}^{\vee}),\mathcal{O}_{X'})=(f^*(\mathcal{F}^{\vee}))^{\vee},$$
and it maybe very hard to construct $(f^*(\mathcal{F}^{\vee}))^{\vee}\to (f^*\mathcal{F})^{\vee\vee}$. Is there a good idea to construct $\alpha$?

[HK04]
B. Hassett, and S. Kovács:
*Reflexive pull-backs and base extension*,
J. Algebraic Geom.
**13**
(2004),
no. 2,
233--247.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, apologies, apparently we didn't write what we had in mind. The only excuse I can try blaming this on is inexperience (at the time)...

So, as stated, this is not true: Let $\dim X\geq 2$, and let $f:X'\to X$ be the blow up of a smooth point $x\in X$ (smooth is for simplicity) and let $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathscr O_X$ denote the ideal sheaf of the point. Further let $E\subseteq X'$ be the exceptional divisor, i.e., the pre-image of the point $x$. Then $\mathcal F^{\vee\vee}\simeq \mathscr O_X$, so $f^*\mathcal F^{\vee\vee}\simeq \mathscr O_{X'}$ and $(f^*\mathcal F)^{\vee\vee}\simeq \mathscr O_{X'}(-E)$, so there is no morphism from the former to the latter.

The key is that you need that the locus where $\mathcal F$ may not be reflexive should not "gain" dimension via $f$.

What we had in mind is how this was used later in the article, namely under the additional condition of Proposition 3.5 and on about the existence of an open set with some nice properties.

The correct statement that we had in mind is that

> Let $f:X'\to X$ be a morphism between $S_2$ schemes which are Gorenstein in codimension $1$ (e.g., normal, or KSB-stable) and $\mathcal F$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. Assume that there exists an open embedding $j:U\hookrightarrow X$ such that
> ${\rm codim}_X(X\setminus U)\geq 2$ as well as
> ${\rm codim}_{X'}(X'\setminus U')\geq 2$, where $j':U'=f^{-1}U\hookrightarrow X'$.
> Further assume that
> $\mathcal F|_U$ is reflexive. Then there exists a natural morphism
> $$
> f^*\mathcal F^{\vee\vee}\to \left(f^*\mathcal F\right)^{\vee\vee}.
> $$

And here is why this is actually true:
The assumptions imply that $\mathcal F^{\vee\vee}\simeq j_*\left(\mathcal F|_U\right)$, so $f^*\mathcal F^{\vee\vee}\simeq f^*j_*\left(\mathcal F|_U\right)$. On the other hand there is a natural transformation of functors $f^*j_*\to j'_*\left(f|_{U'}\right)^*$ which induces a morphism $f^*j_*\left(\mathcal F|_U\right)\to j'_*\left(\left(f|_{U'}\right)^*\mathcal F|_{U}\right)\simeq j'_*\left(f^*\mathcal F|_{U'}\right)$. Finally, as in the beginning, we have that $j'_*\left(f^*\mathcal F|_{U'}\right)\simeq \left(f^*\mathcal F\right)^{\vee\vee}$. The combination of these morphisms gives the desired one.

---

I hope this clears up the confusion our sloppiness caused.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Now, it is clean that the construction of $\alpha$ requires open sets $U,U'$ in $X,X'$ such that the codimensions are $\ge 2$, and $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is reflexive.